# Determine which Friday of the month the date is

Tags: javascript, date, luxon, dayjs

Given a date like `April 22, 2022` how can we accurately determine which Friday of that Month it is. In this case it is the 4th Friday.

I have tried all combinations of adding the week day (0-6, so 5) plus the current day, dividing things by 7, using `%` because it seems cool, etc. At this point I am stumped.

I am using the Luxon library, but also have access to native JS and dayjs

Comment: Can we assume that if we're given a date, it's definitely a Friday?

Comment: Divide 22 by 7 and round up.

Comment: @Barmar Ah.. is that it??? Can that always work!?!? It's too simple..!

Comment: All dates from 1-7 are the 1st dayname of the month, 8-14 are the 2nd, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try this out:

```
function getFriday(day, month, year){
    
    date = new Date(year, month - 1, day)

    if (date.getDay() === 5){
        return Math.ceil(day / 7)
    } else{
        return "Date is not a Friday"
    }
}

console.log(getFriday(21, 1, 2022)) // 3
console.log(getFriday(4, 2, 2022)) // 1
console.log(getFriday(22, 4, 2022)) // 4
console.log(getFriday(15, 5, 2022)) // Date is not a Friday
```

It creates a date object from the function arguments, checks if the date is a Friday, then calculates which Friday it is. If the date is not a Friday, it returns "Date is not a Friday", though this could be removed to return null.

Comment: `Math.floor(((day - 1) / 7) + 1)` is simpler as `Math.ceil(day/7)`. :-)

Comment: @RobG Indeed, you're right! I threw this together rather quickly and didn't notice that. I'll edit the code with your version :)